# Probability that a point is contained in at least one interval (given N equal length intervals)

Tags: probability

> Given a point $x \in [0,T]$ and $N$ intervals of equal length $w<T$, what is the probability of at least one interval containing $x$? The starting positions of the intervals are independently sampled.

My reasoning was:

1. The probability of an interval containing $x$ is $w/T$.
2. The probability of at least one interval containing $x$, $P(\text{at least one}) = P(\text{any one int})$ or $P(\text{any two ints})$ or $\dots$

Therefore, $$P(\text{at least one}) = \sum_{k=1}^{N}\binom{N}{k}\left(\frac{w}{T}\right)^{k}$$

However, that doesn't seem to be it... I would appreciate any help.

Regards,
Misel

Comment: Your sum, in which each term is meant to be the probability of $x$ living in exactly $k$ subintervals, fails to multiply by $\left( \frac {T-w}T\right)^{N-k}$ (as you need $N-k$ of the intervals to NOT contain $x$).  Easier though, to compute the probability that all $N$ intervals miss $x$, so your answer is $1-\left( \frac {T-w}T\right)^{N}$.

Comment: Thanks @lulu, that's it indeed. Much appreciated.

Comment: I have another question though, could this also be expressed using the binomial distribution? The trial would be sampling an interval and the success, containing x? Thanks.

Comment: That's what this is.  $p=\frac wT$ is the probability of success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Presumably the intervals are allowed to overlap.  As you say, the chance of a given interval containing $x$ is $\frac wT$, so the chance that the given interval does not contain $x$ is $1-\frac wT$.  The chance that no interval contains $x$ is ????

Comment: Thanks Ross. Much easier to look at it this way.